# How can I remove the thick blue boundary lines from the qgis2web output?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I created a map of Africa that shows all of Africa's administrative divisions. When I try to export it to a web map, it adds a thick blue line that represents the boundaries of these divisions. How can I remove the thick blue line?[image: Below is the result when I export the map]

Another problem this map has is that when I hover over any of the divisions, a pop up appears that contains info about that division. The popup causes the map to move lower in order to fit. How can I prevent it?

[image: An image showing the pop-up and the map]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Questions: Export to openlayers or leaftlet? Which settings within QGIS for stroke for this layer? (map units?).
Popup: I have no solution, but maybe it could help to delete/hide some columns (without content) for a smaller popup?

Comment: Hi Jurgen, Thank you for the response. I am using leaflet. The map units for the map is degrees. I am working on deleting and hiding some columns. I also learned about auto-pan that can be set to false, however I am not sure if I can do that for this web map.

Comment: Please try for the layer: layer styling - stroke width: o,2 MILLITEMETERS. After this: You can still see the blue thick bounderies?